# URL Connection: What is the difference between the following?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need to know the difference between the following two methods of url connection? 
What is the significance of these two methods?
Which method is preferred in what circumstances?

Method 1: 
    file.h
    #import

```
#define kPostURL @"http://localhost/php/register.php"
#define kemail @"email"
#define kpassword @"password"


@interface signup : UIViewController 
{
...
...
NSURLConnection *postConnection;
}
@property ...
...
@end


file.m

NSMutableDictionary *input=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
...
...
...
NSMutableString *postString = [NSMutableString stringWithString:kPostURL];

[postString appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"?%@=%@", kemail, [input objectForKey:@"email"] ]];
[postString appendString: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&%@=%@", kpassword, [input objectForKey:@"password"] ]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:postString]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

postConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];
NSLog(@"postconnection: %@", postConnection);

NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: postString ]];    
NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSLog(@"serverOutput = %@", serverOutput);
```

Method 2:

```
NSString *post =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@&password=%@",[input objectForKey:@"email"], [input objectForKey:@"password"]];

NSString *hostStr = @"http://localhost/frissbee_peeyush/php/login.php?";
hostStr = [hostStr stringByAppendingString:post];
NSLog(@"HostStr %@",hostStr);
NSData *dataURL =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [ NSURL URLWithString: hostStr ]];    
NSString *serverOutput = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"serverOutput %@", serverOutput);
```

What if i need to connect to url only using header information ?

Problem: for login and signup, these methods are perfectly fine but whenever i want to insert any string containing special characters such as @,/,_ etc, it is unable to perform any operation.

Guide me plz.

Comment: did you encode you special characters properly? (URL-encode)

Comment: i am not using any encoding method for POST method. Could you tell me where to use that, that sounds logical and might be effective if sending special characters along with text

Comment: could you also explain me the difference between the two methods, for whats worth, i only know that first method implies macros method

Comment: cud u plz tell me the coding method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even the method 1 you have implemented is incomplete as there are many delegates of NSUrlConnection which should be implemented to get the data , handling errors , proxy , authentication etc . It is more advisable to use the first method but not in the way you used.NSUrlConnection in asynchronous in behaviour so You Don't have to wait until the url is loaded.

[NSUrlConnection Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsurlconnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

The Second method simply hits the url as sson as it encounters the NSUrl parameter in the NSData . Moreover , you don't have much control over your web service interaction .

[NSUrl Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

To get the implementation of NSUrlConnection you can go through the

[NSUrlConnection Tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/)

```
Url With Special Characters:-
[NSURL URLWithString:[string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

Comment: Hi You will have to use the following way to have nsstring with special characters.[NSURL URLWithString:[string stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

Comment: thnx for your response actually i applied the same concept of encoding but in method one.. it was right there in front of me but i overlooked it... this is what happens when u r fused with drop dead confusion... anyways thnx...